# What does the use of brackets really mean in F#?

Tags: f#

I need help understanding the following statement:

```
let dictionary = [ for i in 1..4 -> i, true ] |> Map.ofSeq
```

Specifically, I am confused about the rules regarding the use of brackets.

1. What does the use of brackets really mean in F#?
2. What type of collection/set do brackets enclose? (i.e. array, seq, list, etc.)
3. Can any expression that returns a collection be used within brackets?

**NOTE**

I know nothing about F#. So please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Brackets are a notation for List initialization. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx Also for sequences you can use `{}` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx Good introduction to F# expressions is here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/expressions-and-syntax.html

Comment: A little warning though, don't mistake using bracket in code (denoting you're using a list) and bracket in type (as shown in interactive or hovering things in visual studio) ; in that case they stand for array. example : `let arr = [| 42 |] // val arr : int [] = [|42|]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just break it up.

```
let step1 = [ for i in 1..4 -> i, true ]
let step2 = step1 |> Map.ofSeq
```

Then you may be able to read the "signatures" of each step:

```
val step1 : (int * bool) list = [(1, true); (2, true); (3, true); (4, true)]
val step2 : Map<int,bool> = map [(1, true); (2, true); (3, true); (4, true)]
```

step1 is then a list so the brackets are for list (list expression).
Inside the list there is a tuple (algebraic data type, product type) of int and bool (int * bool) (note the * for 'product').

step2 is a Map, created from a sequence, and a list is also a sequence so that is the reason why that works (or lists supports the sequence interface). `ofSeq` should be the total giveaway I would guess.

Using `Map.ofList` would probably make it less confusing, but its equivalent

```
let step1 = [ for i in 1..4 -> i, true ]
let step2 = step1 |> Map.ofList 

val step1 : (int * bool) list = [(1, true); (2, true); (3, true); (4, true)]
val step2 : Map<int,bool> = map [(1, true); (2, true); (3, true); (4, true)]
```

You may benefit from reading some documentation like:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233230.aspx

Now send me my certificate from this course of yours... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

These are the used brackets in F#

()

```
(1, 2)                      // Tuple (separator is a comma)
()                          // empty tuple, called unit
```

[]

```
[  1; 2  ]                  // List
[]                          // List.empty 

[| 1; 2 |]                  // Array
[||]                        //  Array.empty
```

{}

```
seq { yield 1; yield 2  }   // Sequence
Seq.empty                   // empty Sequence, not {} 

async { return 1 }          // Computation Expressions, e.g. async

type record =               // Record type definition
    { Name : string 
      Age  : int
    }
```

<>

```
type A<'T> = A of 'T
```

Types can easily be composed

```
let composition = 
    async { return
                [| 
                    [ ("A",1); ("B",2) ]
                    [ ("C",3) ] 
                |]
    }
// val composition : Async<(string * int) list []>
```

Comment: While `()` appears to be an empty tuple, unit is a completely separate type to [`System.Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) (no type arguments). This is not immediately clear given that the syntax overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [ sequence-expression ]
> ```

Creates a List

Other types of brackets create different types of collections eg. [`seq { ... }`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) or [`\[| sequence-expression |\]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) for sequences (`IEnumerable<T>`) or arrays respectively.

> Can any expression that returns a collection be used within brackets?

Sort of. There is a whole load of support for creating various collections (eg. `yield value`) including also merging sub-collections (`yield! expression`).

Really too much for a quick answer. The links about into the F# Reference will show you the scope of this.